# AWS lambda missing events from dynamodb stream

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I am consistently missing lambda triggers from a dynamodb stream. I am mapping the dynamodb stream to the lambda function with event_source_mapping resource.

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "history" {
  event_source_arn  = "${data.aws_dynamodb_table.auditlogDynamoDB.stream_arn}"
  function_name     = "${module.cx-clientcomm-history-lambda.lambda_function_arn}"
  starting_position = "LATEST"
  maximum_retry_attempts = 0
  maximum_record_age_in_seconds = 604800 // adding to explicitly set. QA plan was providing invalid value
  #(Optional) An Amazon SQS queue or Amazon SNS topic destination for failed records. 
  destination_config {
    on_failure {
      destination_arn = "${data.aws_sns_topic.cx-clientcomm-sns-slack.arn}"
    }
  }
}
```

It appears when there are entries in dynamodb are coming it very close to each other, some are not picked up by the event_source_mapping and not sent to the lambda.

Is there a way to make sure this doesn't happen? This needs to be very reliable

Comment: From memory each event can contain several records. Are you reading all of them or just the first one? It will help to see the code of the lambda.

Comment: I am only reading one. I did not realize this could contain multiple records.